# How would the crystal structure of sodium stearate look like?

Tags: ions, solid-state-chemistry

In my lessons of solid state, I was taught about Bravais Lattices, and Face Centered, Body Centered, and Primitive cubic lattices, to name a few. All these crystal structures had this assumption, *that ions/atoms are considered as hard spheres*.

Considering sodium stearate, the stearate anion isn't a *hard sphere*, not by a long shot. Since Bravais lattices assume spherical atoms, I am led to believe that sodium stearate doesn't follow Bravais lattice structures.

So my question is, **what is the crystal structure of sodium stearate?**

Comment: There's quite a bit of difference between atoms and molecules...

Comment: @Mithoron I think I already know that. Can you please be a bit more direct and tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Bravais lattices have nothing to do with atoms as solid spheres, or with atoms **at all**, for that matter.

Comment: Lattices don't assume spherical atoms. There is no assumption of what is placed at each lattice point.

Comment: @orthocresol Perhaps my assumption was wrong. However, all the pictures of these lattices show the lattice points as spheres. How would you accommodate a long chain fatty acid's conjugate base in such a lattice point?

Comment: Stretch the lattice. Note that there's also no assumption about the lattice parameters $a, b, c, \alpha, \beta, \gamma$. Anyway, nobody also said the alkyl chain has to be fully extended; maybe it is, maybe it isn't.

Comment: Maybe take a look at the refined structure of any stearate, say, this one: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/suppl/10.1021/jp992279f (supplementary info would be enough). Pay attention how the structure is obtained, what symmetry it has and what the unit cell looks like.

Comment: @orthocresol Usually it is. Then again, lattice points have nothing to do with atoms; if they coincide, that's merely a coincidence.